# Dynamic Custom Cell - iPhone

Tags: uitableview, custom-cell

I have created a custom UITableviewcell using IB which holds for 1 user. If i need to create the same cell dynamically based on the number of users, what should be done. Could any one please help me with this.

If the data comes for a single user from XML i need to show a single cell with data for 1 user. If the data comes for multiple users, I need to show multiple cells with data. Any help is Appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Get array of all users and send the send the count information in the numberOfRowsInSection UITableViewDataSource method and populate the data based on the array in cellForRowAtIndexPath method.